# Return variable value is not difened

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronization

I have the following function, which i suppose to print out the return value in HTML. The problem is that i get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: retValue is not defined`.

```
function f() {
              var request1 = $.ajax({
                   url : '/a',
                   type: "GET"
              });
              var request2 = $.ajax({
                  url: '/b', 
                  type: 'GET',
              });

              $.when(request1, request2).done(function(result1, result2){

              var retValue
              //do something
              return retValue

          }


    var rows = f();
    $("#status tbody").html(rows);
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can we see your actual code? What you've got here is missing the important parts and seems to be missing a `});`

Comment: You can't really return values from asynchronous requests..